# I have buttons I'm trying to change the titleColor of but I can't change it back to the default color when another button is clicked

Tags: uibutton, swift3

This creates the button:

```
var Todaybutton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: view.frame.size.width/7, height: 44))

Todaybutton.setTitle(dayString + "\n\(dayOfWeekString)", for: UIControlState())
Todaybutton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
Todaybutton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 197/255, green: 197/255, blue: 197/255, alpha: 1.0), for: UIControlState())
Todaybutton.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping;
Todaybutton.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 2
Todaybutton.titleLabel!.textAlignment = .center
Todaybutton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Geomanist-Regular", size: 14.0)!
Todaybutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Home.onTodayButtonClicked),for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(Todaybutton)
```

and here's the button action:

```
 func onTodayButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("button works")
    showHUD()
    searchTxt.text = ""

    sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)

    Tombutton?.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 197/255, green: 197/255, blue: 197/255, alpha: 1.0), for: .disabled)
    TwoDaysbutton?.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 197/255, green: 197/255, blue: 197/255, alpha: 1.0), for: .disabled)
    ThreeDaysButton?.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 197/255, green: 197/255, blue: 197/255, alpha: 1.0), for: .highlighted)
    FourDaysButton?.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 197/255, green: 197/255, blue: 197/255, alpha: 1.0), for: .reserved)
    FiveDaysButton?.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 197/255, green: 197/255, blue: 197/255, alpha: 1.0), for: .selected)
    SixDaysButton?.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 197/255, green: 197/255, blue: 197/255, alpha: 1.0), for: .normal)
```

The code sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal) works and makes the button text black, but then it doesn't change back to 197/255 when another button is tapped. How do I do that?

Comment: What is the meaning of "when another button is tapped", is it Tombutton, TwoDaysbutton and etc.

Comment: @RamkrishnaSharma yes, this setup repeats for 7 buttons total

Comment: You need to implement the addTarget action to all other button in order to view the background color back to "197/255".